# how to add this gauge to vue project

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue for a project. I FOUND a perfectly working gauge that does what I would like it to do, but the issue is getting it inside of my vue setup. I tried creating a new vue instance and adding the component to the page, but no luck. In the sample, they add the component to the main index.html file. In theory, I would like to add it to a single vue page as a component, but can't get that to work either. Can someone look at my file and tell me the issue.

```js
const Gauge = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gauge-bg"></div>
      <div class="gauge-middle"></div>
      <div class="gauge-overlay" :style="{ transform: rotate }"></div>
      <div class="gauge-data">
        <span>{{ percentage }}%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['percentage'],
  computed: {
    rotate() {
      const v = this.percentage * 180 / 100;
      return `rotate(${v}deg)`;
    } } });



new Vue({
  el: 'app',
  components: {
    Gauge } });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gauge-bg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a3f6ba;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-middle {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(250px / 2);
  top: 75px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5df086;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px;
  transform-origin: center top;
}
.gauge-data {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #5df086;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<gauge percentage="33"></gauge>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the `#` sign from your Vue app..

---

***EDIT:*** you were asking how to do this in a `.vue` file - see this CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit Vue Gauge]

---

***You had this:***

```
new Vue({
  el: 'app',  // <<--- INCORRECT
  components: {
    Gauge 
  } 
});
```

***It needed to be:***

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',  // <<--- ADDED # SIGN
  components: {
    Gauge 
  } 
});
```

```js
const Gauge = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gauge-bg"></div>
      <div class="gauge-middle"></div>
      <div class="gauge-overlay" :style="{ transform: rotate }"></div>
      <div class="gauge-data">
        <span>{{ percentage }}%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['percentage'],
  computed: {
    rotate() {
      const v = this.percentage * 180 / 100;
      return `rotate(${v}deg)`;
    } } });



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Gauge 
  } 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gauge-bg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a3f6ba;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-middle {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(250px / 2);
  top: 75px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5df086;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px;
  transform-origin: center top;
}
.gauge-data {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #5df086;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<gauge percentage="33"></gauge>
</div>
```

Comment: what if its in a .vue file? the template is inside of Vue.extend so I know I can't export default {()}

Comment: I have added to my answer - click on the `Edit on CodeSandbox` button...